# How do I subtract a number from a label with text already in it

Tags: c#

enemyHP.Text = "Enemy HP: " + rat.HP.ToString();

How would I do it since I have text in there. I just want to make it so every second it will go down by one.

```
    private void battleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (battleDropBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Rat")
        {
            enemyHP.Text = "Enemy HP: " + rat.HP.ToString();
            enemyDPS.Text = "Enemy DPS: " + rat.Damage.ToString();


            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dealDamage();
    }

    public void dealDamage()
    {
    }
```

Comment: `dealDamage` isn't doing anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reduce the `rat.HP` value instead, and then update the label.

```
public void dealDamage()
{
    rat.HP--;
    enemyHP.Text = "Enemy HP: " + rat.HP.ToString();
}
```